# PHP Y SQLServer

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, aplicación-web

Necesito ayuda para registrar datos desde `PHP` hacia una base de datos `SQLServer`.

Estos son los datos de conexión:
$server:"10.10.2.120";
$user:"admin";
$pass:"123456";

```js
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Registrar clientes</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/validar.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" onSubmit="return validaL();">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="imagenes/logo-oxford.png" width="90%" height="10%">
    </div>
    <h2>Ingresar clientes</h2>
  <div class="input_style">
  <input type="text" name="cod" placeholder="Codigo auxiliar"required>
  <input type="text" name="nom" placeholder="Nombre"required>
  <input type="text" name="rut" placeholder="Rut"required>
  <input type="text" name="act" placeholder="Activo"required>
  <input type="text" name="fon" placeholder="Telofono"required>
  <input type="text" name="em" placeholder="Email"required>
  <input type="text" name="dire" placeholder="Direccion"required>
  <input type="submit" value="Guardar" id="btn_ingresar" class="btn">
  </div>
</form>
<div class="resbueno">
<?php echo "Cliente registrado"; ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>


<?php 

require 'conexion.php';

$nombre = $_POST['cod'];
$nombre = $_POST['nom']; 
$rut = $_POST['rut']; 
$fono = $_POST['act'];
$fono = $_POST['fon']; 
$correo=$_POST['email'];
$direcion=$_POST['dire']; 

$comprobar=$con->query("SELECT Cod FROM clientes WHERE Cod=$cod");
if($con->$query($comprobar)==true){
 echo"El cliente ya esta registrado ";
  echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
}else{
$insertarc= "insert into clientes (cod,nom,rut,fono,direccion)values ('$cod',$nom','$rut','$fono','$direc');";

$ejecutar = $con->query($insertarc);

if(!$ejecutar){
    printf("Error en ejecución: %s\n", $con->error);
 echo "0<br>";
echo "<br>";echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
}else{
    echo "El vendedor de registro exitosamente en la BD ";
 echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
}
}

 
?>
```

```html
clase conexion
<?php
 
  $server:"10.10.2.120"
  $user = "admin";
  $pass = "123456";
 
  $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Prueba1", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"pass");
 $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $servidor, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));
}else{
 echo "CONECTADO";
}

/* Iniciar la transacción. */
if ( sqlsrv_begin_transaction( $conn ) === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));
}

/* Inicializar los parámetros. */
$orderId = 1; $qty = 10; $productId = 100;

?>
```

$bd:"Prueba1";
Datos de la tabla : inser into clientes (cod,nom,rut,fono,direccion)values ('$cod',$nom','$rut','$direc');

Comment: Da más información por favor. Que intentaste? Te genera algún error?

Comment: ok,pondre lo que intente

Comment: `$con->query("SELECT Cod FROM clientes WHERE Cod=$cod")` la variable `$con` no está definida en ningún lado. En `conexion.php` definís `$conn` (con doble N). Puede que sea ese el problema. Te devuelve algún error?

Comment: ah si me percate de ese error

Comment: ¿No deberías usar [`sqlsrv_query`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-query.php) en lugar de `$con->query` para hacer la consultas?

Comment: Utilize eso peroo me arroja un error diciendo que qery no era un objeto,sin envargo cuando trabajo con my sql no tengo ningun problema